# Let $C$ be a set of sets defined as follows,

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computational-complexity

I'm in Theory of Computation, I've already taken Set Theory so I'm familiar with the terminology but this question is not making sense to me.

Let $C$ be a set of sets defined as follows:

1. $\emptyset\in C$
2. If $S_1\in C$ and $S_2\in C$ then $\{S_1, S_2\}\in C$.
3. If $S_1\in C$ and $S_2\in C$ then $S_1\times S_2\in C$.
4. Nothing is in $C$ except that which follows from (1), (2), and (3).

b) Give an example of a set $S$ of ordered pairs such that $S\in C$, and $|S|>1$

c) Does $C$ contain any infinite sets?

d) Is $C$ countable or uncountable?

I'm not looking for an answer, just a way of understanding what exactly is going on and a way to find the answer would be a lifesaver!

Thank you!

Comment: I just wanted to explain what condition (4) means.  It means that if $D$ is any set that satisfies conditions (1), (2), and (3), then $C$ is a subset of $D$.  To put it another way, $C$ is the intersection of all sets $D$ which satisfy conditions (1), (2), and (3).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, IMHO you made it even more complicated... I'd suggest the OP ignore (4) for the moment of constructing the set.

Comment: @ftfish Yes, I agree, the OP should ignore (4) for the time being, at least until later on in the problem.

Comment: It is not clear to me that such a set $C$ exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to 1 and 2, the set $\{\emptyset,\emptyset\} = \{\emptyset\}$ is in $C$ (taking $S_1=S_2=\emptyset$). Note this is *not* the empty set, for it's not empty.

According again to 1 and 2 and the fact we just proved, the set $s:=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ is in the set. (Taking $S_1=\emptyset$, $S_2=\{\emptyset\}$).

According to 3, taking $S_1=S_2=s$, we have $t:=\{(\emptyset,\emptyset),(\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}),(\{\emptyset\},\emptyset),(\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset\})\}$ in the set. Note the round parentheses, meaning ordered pairs, introduced by the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Comment: Thank you, that was part a) actually. I figured that out similarly to how you've done it. What I'm struggling with is understanding how ordered pairs can come into play. If we let $S=\{(a,b),(c,d)\}$ for example, we can have $\{S,\emptyset\}$, but how do I know that's in $C$?

Comment: @roboguy12 that is what (3) introduces. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. But do we know anything other than constructions based on the empty set?

Comment: @roboguy12, No. That is what $C$ and this problem itself are based on..

Comment: Ok good, because now it makes sense. So clearly there are no infinite sets in $C$ because for $S, T\in C$ $|\{S, T\}| = |S|+|T|$ and $|S\times T|=|S|*|T|$. But it's uncountable because there are infinitely many ways to combine elements of $C$ using either (2) or (3), right? I can't think of a way in which $C$ could be countable.

Comment: The cardinality of $\{S,T\}$ is not the in general the cardinality of $S$ plus the cardinality of $T$. The cardinality is two. The two elements are the sets, $S$ and $T$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm really smart. So the elements of $C$ either have cardinality of 1 due to (1), 2 due to (2), or powers of 2 due to (3).

Comment: @roboguy12 I'm sorry I'm not sure about the countability of $C$.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we will see that the set, $C$ is countable and contains only finite sets. To do this we will construct a sequence of sets, $$C_0\subset C_1\subset C_2\cdots$$ such that $C_0=\emptyset$ and $\bigcup_{n\geq 0} C_n=C$. We define these sets inductively. Suppose that $C_n$ has been constructed. Since we are only able to construct only those things that follow from (1), (2), and (3), we construct the set $C_{n+1}$ as follows: for any pair of sets in $C_n$, $X,Y$, we form two new sets, $\{X,Y\}$, and $X\times Y$ (some of theses sets may have been constructed already, but we do get some new sets). Thus we set 
$$C_{n+1}=\{\{X,Y\}:X,Y\in C_n\}\cup\{X\times Y:X,Y\in C_n\}.$$ Note that $C_{n+1}$ are exactly the elements that follow directly from the construction rules and $C_n$. Thus the union over all $C_n$ is the desired set, $C$.

We will now prove that each set, $C_n$ is finite, by induction. Note that $C_0$ is finite since it just contains the empty set. Now if $C_n$ is finite, so are the sets $\{\{X,Y\}:X,Y\in C_n\}$, and $\{X\times Y:X,Y\in C_n\}$, we construct two  elements for each pair of elements from $C_n$. But since the countable union of countable sets is countable, the set, $C$ is countable.

We will likewise prove that each element of $C$ is finite, again by induction. Note that the only element of $C_0$ is the empty set, so it is finite. Now suppose that all elements of $C_n$ are finite. We now show that all elements of $C_{n+1}$ are finite.Let $X,Y\in C_n$. But all elements of the form, $\{X,Y\}$ have cardinality two ,and all elements of the from of the form $X\times Y$ have cardinality $|X|\times |Y|$ but by induction since $X$ and $Y$ have finite cardinality, so does, $X\times Y$.